# Monogame - sprite not rotating around origin point

Tags: rotation, xna, sprite, monogame

I'm trying to rotate a sprite around its center with following code:

```
            Vector2 origin = new Vector2(position.Width / 2, position.Height / 2);

            s.Draw(position, origin, angle, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, sourceRectangle, color, rotation, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Note: Since I'm drawing from a sprite sheet, the source rectangle is being calculated.

The original size of my sprite is 15x32. If I use this size, the rotation looks nearly correct but it's still a little bit shifted:

[image]

However, when I resize the width and height to 75x128 the sprite is completely displaced:

[image]

Is there a way to always place the sprite correct, when resizing it? And why is the sprite even displaced when drawing it in the original size?

By the way, the green box is the origin point with the size of the sprite.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out myself!

When creating the origin point, I used the new Width and Height (75, 128) but one has to use the width and height of the original sprite. In this case (15, 32).